# How can I use EF Core to display data from 3 different tables in my application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 3 different tables, `Customer`, `Vehicle`, `Contact`.

The customer and vehicle tables share the common key `ReferenceID` and the customer and contact table share the key `ContactID`.

I want to be able to use EF core to display data from all three tables and was wondering if there is a way to do it without using JOIN?

Below is my attempt but I get this error: SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Vehicle")]
    public string ReferenceID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public string ContactID { get; set;}
    public ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public string ReferenceID { get; set;}
    public string Make {get; set;}
}

public class Contact
{
    public string ContactID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `JOINS` here, You already have the access to the other tables as Navigation Property. If you are not using the Lazy loading the properties `Vehicle` and `Contact` will load their data.

If the values didn't get load, you can load them as below.

```
var customers = _context.Customers.Include("Contact").Include("Vehicle");
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error: SqlException: Invalid object name 'Customers' even though I have 
``` public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact>Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }```

Comment: `Customers` is not a DbSet as per your comment. In that case you will get that error. You get that error when you wrongly type your table name. Eg: your table name in db is `my_table`, and when you write a query `SELECT * FROM my_table` this will work and when you miss spell the table name `SELECT * FROM my_tables` this will give you the error `Invalid object name my_tables`